# putting some class methods in different .cc file

Tags: c++

I have a bit of code of the following format contained in a single .h and .cc file:

myClass.h:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H
class myClass
{
public:
    myClass(); // constructor
    ~myClass(); // destructor

    void classMethod1 ();
    void classMethod2 ();

    int memberVarable1;
    int memberVariable2;
};
#endif
```

and myClass.cc:

```
#include "myClass.h"
myClass::myClass(){
 // stuff
}

myClass::~myClass(){
 // stuff
}

void myClass::classMethod1 (){
 // stuff
}

void myClass::classMethod2 (){
 // stuff
}
```

All of this is working fine. However my project is getting quite large and I'm about to add a set of new functionality. Instead of clogging up myClass.h and myClass.cc I want to put some new methods in another .cc file. I don't seem to be able to get this to work though.

myClass.h:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include "secondFile.h"

class myClass
    {
    public:
        myClass(); // constructor
        ~myClass(); // destructor

        void classMethod1 ();
        void classMethod2 ();

        int memberVarable1;
        int memberVariable2;
    };
#endif
```

and myClass.cc:

```
#include "myClass.h"
#include "secondFile.h"
myClass::myClass(){
 // stuff
}

myClass::~myClass(){
 // stuff
}

void myClass::classMethod1 (){
 // stuff
}

void myClass::classMethod2 (){
 // stuff
}
```

secondFile.h:

```
#ifndef SECONDFILE_H
#define SECONDFILE_H

void someNewMethod();

#endif
```

secondFile.cc

```
#include "secondFile.h"
void someNewMethod(){
 // can't see classMethod1()
}
```

Comment: Define like this:

void myClass::classMethod1 (){
 // stuff
}

void myClass::classMethod2 (){
 // stuff
}

Comment: I can see lots of problems, but I'm sure that many of those problems are not in your real code, they're just mistakes you've made in transcribing your real code to this post. So please fix the post so it's like your real code. Otherwise you are going to get answers which have nothing to do with your real problem.

Comment: Also, are you using a makefile?

Comment: @PeterL. yeah saw that.. Make is complicated (this is just a snippet of a much bigger project)

Comment: @john care to point some out? this is close to my real code.

Comment: two answers, three comments, and two upvotes in ~20 seconds. Thanks for the real time help everyone!

Comment: You've fixed some of the issues, classMethod1 and classMethod2 now really are class methods. I think one unclear issue is whether someNewMethod is meant to be a method of myClass, or whether it's meant to be a global function. It would also help to see what code you are using when you can't see classMethod1.

Comment: yes I mean someNewMethod to be a method of myClass. Answers below helped me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In every source file, you need to include every header file that declares functions, etc. you want to use.

So in your case, it seems like you want secondFile.cc to contain

```
#include "myClass.h"
#include "secondFile.h"
void someNewMethod(){
 // can't see classMethod1()
}
```

Btw, what you are doing is quite common to do in practice. Sometimes, I go even further than what you suggest, and implement the various methods of a single class in multiple source files. For large, complicated classes, this helps speed up the development cycle because I only have to recompile a fraction of the class implementation if I only made a small change. Example:

myclass.h

```
#pragma once

class MyClass
{
  ...
  void complicatedMethod0();
  void complicatedMethod1();
  ...
};
```

myclass_impl0.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"

void MyClass::complicatedMethod0()
{
  ...
}
```

myclass_impl1.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"

void MyCLass::complicatedMethod1()
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Great! can I (should I) put the method declarations in secondFile.h or keep everything in myClass.h?

Comment: @tir38 That depends. If you are adding methods to your class, they have to go in the same header file. You cannot spread the class declaration over multiple header files. Otherwise, do whatever works best for you.

Comment: *"In every source file, you need to include every header file that defines functions, etc. you want to use."* - this is not true, only the function declarations are required - finding the definitions is the linker's job. They don't need to be in header files either, you can forward declare.

Comment: @JBentley You're right, I tend to get the declaration/definition terminology mixed up sometimes. Fixing... As for forward declaring, I generally shy away from it as it violates the DRY principle and is rather brittle.

Comment: so I don't need to tell myclass.h about either.cpp file? It knows about both?

Answer (score 1):

If you are intending to *add* methods to `myClass`, you can't do that - the class methods have to be contained in one definition.

You can *extend* `myClass`, however, by *inheriting* from it:

secondFile.h:

```
#ifndef SECONDFILE_H
#define SECONDFILE_H

#include "myClass.h"

class mySecondClass : public myClass
{
    public: 
        void someNewMethod();
}
#endif
```

secondFile.cc

```
#include "secondFile.h"
void mySecondClass::someNewMethod(){
     this.classMethod1();
}
```

Comment: So in this way, one instance of myClass can create one instance of mySecondClass. Then the instance mySecondclass knows about all public and protected (but not private) methods and variables of the instance of myClass?

Comment: No, it's the same instance.  It's both a `mySecondClass` _and_ a `myClass`.  In the same way a Giraffe is a Mammal and an Animal.  Read up on inheritance to gain a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "secondFile.h"
#include "myClass.h" 
//if you want the class methods, 
//you need to tell the compiler where to look
void someNewMethod(){
 // can't see classMethod1()
}
```

it seems you've forgotten to include "myClass.h".